# Getting a ksplice error after installing from ubuntu software center

Tags: package-management

There's a red circular icon with a white horizontal dash in my taskbar which says : An error ocurred, please run package manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. THe error message was: Unknown error: 'class 'SystemError'> E: the package ksplice-uptrack needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

I tried sudo apt-get remove uptrack and sudo apt-get --purge remove uptrack. After reading state information it just says : E: The package ksplice-uptrack needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Can't access ubuntu software center, software updater; and firefox is spontaneously closing.

Comment: Okay, I think I might have figured out a way. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ksplice and https://www.ksplice.com/uptrack/manual-installation#. I went through these two pages and following the directions was able to get ksplice running (supposedly) then I did sudo apt-get --purge remove ksplice and sudo apt-get autoremove. The only file leftover I can see is ksplice.list.save.1 ; It keeps saying I can't remove it because it has an invalid file extension and I don't have permission? I'm the only user on my desktop.

Comment: Actually, there is also a file ksplice.list and ksplice.list.save in etc/apt/sources.list.d. The same place where ksplice.list.save.1 is. And I just looked up ksplice in unity and I found it. It's still there. Even though terminal tells me that both ksplice and uptrack are not installed.